# bbb qunit testing

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit, backbone-boilerplate

I use backbone boilerplate for my project and have a problems with testing it. For tests I use QUnit. For example, test collection:

tests/index.html

```
<html>
<head>

...qunit.js, qunit.css, other libraries...

<script data-main="../../app/config" src="../../vendor/js/libs/require.js"></script>
<!-- Declare your test files to be run here -->
<script>
  QUnit.config.autostart = false;
  // Ensure you point to where your tests are, base directory is app/, which
  // is why ../test is necessary
  require({
    paths: {
      tests: "../test/qunit/tests"
    }
  }, [

    // Load the example tests, replace this and add your own tests
    // "tests/example",

    "tests/sites/collections"

  ], QUnit.start);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

tests/sites/collections.js

```
define(['modules/sites'], function (Sites) {
  module("module sites collection", {
    setup: function () {
      this.collection = new Sites.Collection();
    }
  });

  test("URL of sites collection.", function () {
    expect(1);
    equal(this.collection.url, 'http://bbb-example.x:8001/sites');
  });
});
```

my grunt.js file in the section test look this:

```
qunit: {
  all: ["test/qunit/*.html"]
},
```

when I open browser window all ok, I see my test:

```
Tests completed in 385 milliseconds.
1 assertions of 1 passed, 0 failed.
```

but when I try to run it in console, I see the strange error:

```
~/projects/JS-bbb-example$ bbb test
Running "qunit:all" (qunit) task
Testing index.html
<WARN> PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing QUnit start() call. Use --force to continue. </WARN>

Aborted due to warnings.
>> 0 assertions passed (0ms)

Done, but with warnings.
```

Maybe you know this problem and know how it can be resolve? Thanks for help.